# How to get rid of error c2061;syntax error cout?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

hello i want to build a programme that display even and odd numbers from given numbers
i get this message error which is error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cout'
i try again to look but i cant find any.i search online and says that i should using  instead of  which i did but it didnt work too. How to solve this

below is my code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int number;
    int firstNum,secondNum;
    int countOdd,countEven;

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> firstNum;

   cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> secondNum;

if (firstNum>secondNum )
    cout << "Sorry the first number must be less than second number";

else if

    cout << "Odd numbers in given range are: ";
    for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)

         if(number % 2 !=0)
             cout << number<< " ";
     countOdd = number;
     cout << "\nTotal count of odd number is :" << countOdd << endl;

    printf("\nEven numbers in given range are: ");
    for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)

         if(number % 2 ==0)
             cout << number << " ";
 countEven = number;
     cout << "\nTotal count of even number is :" << countEven << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have an `else if` without a test condition. Remove the `if` from that line.

Comment: Instead of  else if ,just write else,if you donot want to write any condition

Comment: Don't forget to initialize countOdd, countEven to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with your `else statement`. here is how you should write it:

```
else {    
   cout << "Odd numbers in given range are: ";
   for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)
         if(number % 2 !=0){
             cout << number<< " ";
             countOdd++;
         }
   cout << "\nTotal count of odd number is :" << countOdd << endl;

   printf("\nEven numbers in given range are: ");
   for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)    
        if(number % 2 ==0){
             cout << number << " ";
             countEven++;
        }
   cout << "\nTotal count of even number is :" << countEven << endl;
}
```

also, don't forget to initialize `countOdd` and `countEven` to zero at the beginning of your program.

Comment: thank you for helping me out. it works the way i wanted too you don't know how much has you helped me with that total count that got me thinking like three days.

Comment: want to ask question.. sorry if it sounds dumb but how countOdd++ makes it count the total number.. is it some type of special case of function or what i hope you can explain because im new to c++

Comment: @KentooMmta suppose firstNum = 1 and secondNum = 10. initial value for countOdd is 0. now the loop starts. number= 1, because it is an odd number, countOdd will be incremented by 1, then number becomes 2, it is not an odd number so the value of countOdd won't change. on next iteration number=3, this is also an odd number, hence countOdd is incremented. this process continues until number=10. the same thing happens for countEven.

Comment: Try to run your code on paper, you will understand everything. good luck learning c++ !